# Create an SQL database programmatically c#

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to create an SQLite database programmatically in C# - by coding.

I was using an XML to store information I needed in my application but it has gotten to the stage where the amount of data being read from the XML is such that the performance of the application is suffering.

As I understand it SQLite databases can be read from and added to faster using the provided System.data.Sqlite functionality.

Is this correct?

[edit]
In addition I should mention i'm doing all this in unity 3d with Monodevelop.

Comment: Why SQLite and not SQL CE or SQL Server Express? Why programmatically?

Comment: Programmatically because the user needs to be able to create and add through the applications GUI. SQLite because it was what I came across when seeking an alternative to XML. Do you recommend one of the other choices?

Comment: SQL CE is free, very lightweiht and supported by MS. Some systems, like Umbraco, use it as backend DB. Making a DB is as easy as making it with SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you don't even need to explicitly create an SQLite database to work with it, just put its name in a connection string and it will be automatically created when you create a table in it.

Comment: I see, at the moment when trying this I am told that I am using an invalid connection string. I've tried googling but nothing seems to work. Can you advise?

Comment: fixed it. Unity hadn't linked properly so copied the dll files i needed into asset folder.

Comment: If you want to have a good support for .NET Framework technologies,  and a ligthweight DB, and are used to T-SQL, managing DBs with SSMS, using technologies like Linq To SQL or Entity Framework, you should use SQL CE. If you want a DB not very well supported by MS, for which you nedd to find tools for managing and using those technologies, then use SQLite.

Comment: @JotaBe, I don't think he's going to be able to run SQL CE everywhere Unity3d runs...

Comment: According to his new edit, of course he can't use SQL CE because it's not managed code, but native. In this case, SQLite is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

you could use code-first feature in Entity framework: the 4.0 capable providers also add DeleteDatabase/CreateDatabase/DatabaseExists functionality.

more info at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-walkthrough.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Use SQL Server CE.

You can create a database file like this:

[Create a SQL Server Compact Edition Database with C#](http://arcanecode.com/2007/01/25/create-a-sql-server-compact-edition-database-with-c/)

I'd use this because is "official" MS database. So it will work fine with MS technologies (Linq to SQL, Entity framework, etc.) It's also a very lightweight DB. Take into acount that there's also available SQL Server Express, but that's not such a lightweight database.

Code to create database:

```
  string connectionString;
  string fileName = “ArcaneCode.sdf”;
  string password = “arcanecode”;

  connectionString = string.Format(
    “DataSource=\”{0}\”; Password=’{1}’”, fileName, password);

  SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
  en.CreateDatabase();
```

Distributing it only requires copying a few small assemblies (for example the installer for [SQL Server CE 2005](http://Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%202005%20Compact%20Edition) it's a 1.7Mb .msi file which results in 7 assemblies) Zero configuration. And there are versions which can be used with .NET framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 (version SQL Server 2005 up to SQL CE 4.0).

If someone can't see the adavantage of being supported by MS, so that using it with C# and otherMS technologies, and having a good documentation on MSDN.

I suppose that I got downvotes because someone is allergic to MS. If not, let me know why.

Comment: The OP asked for creating SQLite dbs, not MS SQL CE dbs. Using sqlite may even be a requirement for interoperability with other programs, or the only feasible option when using it on OSX/Linux etc.

Comment: The title of the question asks for the way of creating a "SQL database". Fully generic question. The OP proposes the use of SQLite as a solution, but SQL Server CE was a good, lightweight and easy to use option until he added he is using Monodevelop. So, well, the answer doesn't apply any more after his edit to the question, but the content of this answer still applies to the title, to the original question, and is well explained and a working solution. Anyway, that's my opinion and you can do whatever you want with your negative votes.